# NuGet - Error when generating nuspec file

Tags: nuget

When I run `nuget.exe pack` for a project, I get the following error:

```
EXEC : warning : 1 issue(s) found with package 'Company.LibName'.

  Issue: Specify version of dependencies.
  Description: The version of dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json' is not specified.
  Solution: Specifiy the version of dependency and rebuild your package.
```

(Specify typo is actually in the message.)

The offending line in the `.nuspec` file is the last line below:

```
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework="net45">
    <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" />
```

However, I don't want specify a version. And I didn't think I needed to, see documentation:

https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#specifying-dependencies-in-version-2.0-and-above

What's the deal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its just a warning and to be ignored.

It seems it only warns for one package, so although it appears to have singled-out Newtonsoft.Json as needing a version, if I reorder the dependencies, it's always the first one in the list (without a version) that invokes the warning.